# Cannot use object of type Closure as array magento 2 during setup upgrade

Tags: magento2

Cannot use object of type Closure as array when run the setup upgrade.
When we try to run the php bin/magento setup:upgrade command. it's given below error. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php on line 1288

Comment: can you be more specific about the issue? share the screenshot of the error if possible.

Comment: When we try to run the php bin/magento setup:upgrade command. it's given below error. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array in /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php on line 1288